# form input values gone after showing errors

Tags: php, jquery, forms, input

i have a problem on my register form ,
when someone fills the form and there are some missing inputs , my PHP code will run that there are some information missing , the problem is the form will reset , the right information are not shown as values for their inputs ,this will make the user fill the whole form again even if he makes only one mistake

i've tried `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>` and register.php as forms actions

Comment: maybe use jquery validate

Comment: post your code..it will help to answer you better..and as @brandelizer has said, why are you not using jquery at front end and later have a check at backend with PHP

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if the informations filled by the user are missing or wrong BEFORE sending the values to the other page. 
For example you have in `register.html` a form like that :

```
<form method="POST" name="form1" action="page.php" onsubmit="return fieldCheck()">
```

and at the end of `ini.html` simply create a javascript function that will check the differents fields like :

```
<script>
    function fieldCheck (){
        var var1 = document.getElementById('va1').value; // here you put every var you want to check in your form by using their id

        if(var1 == "" || var1 == " "){
            alert("Please fill var1");
            return false; // The form WILL NOT submit
        } else { // if everything is OK then you can submit the form
            return true; 
        }
    }
    </script>
```

So, if the datas are not correctly filled, the form won't submit and you won't lose your datas because the user will not be redirected

There is another solution : add `required` in the `input` the user MUST fill. If he doesn't, there will be a little box saying that the field needs to be filled

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you need to set the values retrieved by the server back to the resulting page.

For for example if your sending page has the following configuration.

```
<form action="index.htm" method="POST">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname"<br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname"<br>
</form>
```

When the user submits you should receive two values:

`$_GET["fname"]` and `$_GET["lname"]`

In this case at the start of `index.html` you should store the received values, then do your validation checking. If the validation check fails then just send the page back with default values set

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $fname=$_POST['lname'];
    $lname=$_POST['fname'];
}

// your validation code
?>
...
<form action="index.htm" method="POST">
  First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo (isset($fname))?$fname:'';?>"<br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo (isset($lname))?$lname:'';?><br>
</form>
```